# Chromedriver closes after running nohup on google cloud

Tags: linux, selenium, google-cloud-platform, selenium-chromedriver, cloud

I have got a simple script which uses `selenium` and chromedriver. I have installed the chrome. When I run the script using the command `nohup python3.7 -u main.py & tail -f nohup.out` everything works; script works as it should. When I close the window of the `google cloud ssh` the scripts stop working. When I reopen the `ssh` and call `tail -f nohup.out` I receive such an error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: headless chrome=75.0.3770.142)
```

I was using the chrome version `87` and read that downgrading it should help, so I downgrade it to `75`.
It is run on ubuntu, chrome and chromedriver version are 75. Is there such a command that would make chromedriver not close after closing the ssh window?

Comment: is --no-sandbox  , and --disable-gpu also set ?

Comment: make sure these flags are set

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/chrome-desktop-remote-on-compute-engine

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @cakelover yeah, switched to using `screen`

Comment: What I ended up doing was just `apt update`, `apt upgrade` and `reboot` (fixed it)

Answer (score 0):

You can start processes in background in Linux. They will continue running even when you log off (which closing SSH window essentially is).

There are several ways:

1. Using `bg` & `disown` - as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/222855/1064087)
2. Using `screen` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/8657/1064087)

You can go through entire thread to get more ideas. I'd recommend using `bg` & `disown` - it works well on Ubuntu provided by GCP however you can try out various solutions and pick the one that suits your needs the best.

From my experience - I was using `screen` for many things - including virtualbox and it worked - it may be more cumbersome if you want many processes to run in background but if that's just one its pretty easy.

Install screen: `sudo apt install screen`, run it with `screen` and treat it as another screen, run whatever you want and then just press <kbd>ctrl + a d</kbd> and you will be back to "original" shell. If you want to resume yor screen sessions type `screen -r`. You will find even more about [using `screen` here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue working "Linux Screen Sessions"

Opena new Terminal

Screen -S tanSessionName

run the process - if you close the Terminal the process continues running

```
python3.9 pythonScript.py
```